# ganymed SSH2 java

Tags: java, ssh

I am using ganymed SSH2 java library to connect to a server using public key authentication.
I have created the public/private key pair and uploaded the public key (mykey.pub) to my server in the /.ssh2 directory. I have the private key on my machine locally.

Info on keys: 2048-bit dsa key pair (ssh2)

I am doing something like this:

```
File keyfile = new File("C:\\keys\\mykey");                  
String keyfilePass = "a"; // will be ignored if not needed

        try
        {

            Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
            conn.connect();


            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPublicKey("myusername", keyfile, keyfilePass); 
           //I get an error at this line
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid PEM structure, '-----BEGIN...' missing
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.crypto.PEMDecoder.parsePEM(PEMDecoder.java:138)
```

Can anyone help?
Is there any other library that works better than this?

EDIT: Key FILE

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----
Subject: username    Comment: "2048-bit dsa, username@host, Tue Jul 31 2012 13:12:48 -\
0500"
KEY   
---- END SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----
```

SOLUTION:

I figured the problem out, the key had to be converted to OPENSSH format (I used puttygen for that). This java library only accepts private keys in openssh format.

Comment: Can you post your key file... maybe replace the actual key with *KEY*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for yourself that the key isn't in the expected format. How did you generate it?

Answer (score 2):

The header "BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY" means that your private key has been generated by the proprietary ssh system from ssh.com.

> Is there any other library that works better than this?

JSch will accept it if your key is not ciphered.